# Tomcat Time Zone

Tags: java, tomcat, timezone

I have to host the same application for users in 2 different timezones. My application does not do any time zone conversion of any sort.

Is it possible to host 2 instances of tomcat on the same server machine and set up each one to have its own timezone ? What pitfalls should I be aware of in doing this ?

I need all my date / time related java code and jdbc calls in my web application to inherit the timezone for the respective Tomcat instance

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is a user go live somewhere else? What if you have 50 timezones to support? That doesn't scale very well. Every user should have its own timezone, and you should format/parse dates using the user's timezone instead of the default one. Everything should be stored in UTC in the database.

Comment: I agree with you. It does not scale very well. But I have a very specific customer who will utmost have all users in 2 timezones and is not willing to invest in another application server. Of course I have huge application 6 years in field and does not use UTC for all its date / time manipulations. The problem is only in the application layer, my database is capable of handling the issue.